# couchbase bucket goes down when defining a view

Tags: couchbase, bucket

I have `couchbase server 3.0.3` installed on `redhat linux`.
Everything works fine until i try to define a new view. When i try to define a view from web ui, the bucket i try this in goes down and goes into a continuous fail-and-restart mode.

It never comes up. Works fine when i delete the bucket and re-add it but stays fine until i try to define a view. Views work fine on my osx installation, on my macbook.

From the log:

> Shutting down bucket "audit" on 'ns_1@172.....' for deletion   ns_memcached000 ns_1@172.....   01:51:46 - Sat Apr 4, 2015
>   Bucket "audit" loaded on node 'ns_1@172.....' in 0 seconds. ns_memcached000 ns_1@172.....   01:51:29 - Sat Apr 4, 2015
>   Shutting down bucket "audit" on 'ns_1@172.....' for server shutdown ns_memcached000 ns_1@172.....   01:51:29 - Sat Apr 4, 2015
>   Shutting down bucket "audit" on 'ns_1@172.....' for server shutdown (repeated 16 times) ns_memcached000 ns_1@172.....   01:51:27 - Sat Apr 4, 2015
>   Bucket "audit" loaded on node 'ns_1@172.....' in 0 seconds. (repeated 16 times) ns_memcached000 ns_1@172.....   01:51:27 - Sat Apr 4, 2015

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a bug in the server. While this is not answering your question, I recommend you to create a ticket on the bugtracker (http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB) and include the generated zip file from the cbcollectinfo command (after you've exhibited the issue).